# How to retrieve a default row when a mysqli_stmt_fetch fails?

Tags: php, mysql, security, parameterized-query

I've got a simple PHP script that pull a row from a MySQL database based on a URL GET parameter, just an int called, say, ID.

If the GET parameter were to be an invalid ID for the database, such as someone enters an int that's not a row in the DB, or they try and enter a character or something, I'd like to display a default record.

The following code actually works, but I feel that it's bad code. I'm just not sure why, or what I should do. I know I should validate ID is an int before I run the database queries, but that doesn't solve what to do when an integer that is an invalid ID is used.

So to make this a proper question, how should I recover from mysqli_stmt_fetch returning false?

Go easy, I know I'm a nub :-)

```
$ID = (int)$_GET["id"];

$query = "SELECT `col1`, `col2`, `col3` FROM `table` WHERE `ID` = ?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $ID);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $var1, $var2, $var3);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
    {   
        $ID = 1; //A record I know exists and will always exist
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $ID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $var1, $var2, $var3);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

OK, so with some feedback and experimentation I've cast the ID as an int in PHP and changed the SQL query to this:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`, `col3`
FROM `table`
WHERE `ID` = ?
UNION
SELECT `col1`, `col2`, `col3`
FROM `table`
WHERE `ID` = 1
LIMIT 1
```

This works for all cases I can think of and seems to be secure. Any problems? Any better than what I had?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check incoming $ID for char and so and set it to value that never be as ID in your table, then use query

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE ID = :id
union all 
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE ID = 1 /* may :defaut_id if */
where not exist (select 1 from table WHERE ID = :id)
```

Comment: I ended up going for a variation of this. Casting the ID to an int in PHP meant that I'd always end up with an ID of 0 (if ID string began non-numeric) or whatever int began the string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the default record has an id, then it could be done in a single query:

```
select ...
from ...
where (id = ?) or (id = $default_id)
```

and just hard-code the default ID into the query string.

Comment: Had a go with this today. It displays a default row when the ID is invalid, but it also displays the default row when the ID _is_ valid (default having an ID of 1 in this case).

Comment: I suppose an xor instead of an or would handle that as well. "one or the other but not both".

Comment: I tried XOR as well, but on MySQL 5.1 when used with phpMyAdmin it returned both rows when the ID was valid. And, since it orders by ID by default I can't use limit since it would return the default. To get around that then I need to order the results, which works, but then I can't arbitrarily change the default ID. Hmmm.